# jquery onclick penetrating to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, parent-child

How would I stop `onclick` for an inner element from also clicking through to its parent element.

```
<div id="1" onclick="alert('1')">
<div id="2" onclick="alert('2')"></div>
</div>
```

If the second div (id="2") is visibly on top of the first, and it is clicked, You will get both alerts 1 & 2.

How can I avoid this so I only get the alert from what I'm (visibly) clicking on, 
Without completely disabling any onclick function the outer div may possess.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/DPCx8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
​var outer = document.getElementById('outer');
outer.onclick = function(event)
    {
        alert('outer');
        event.stopPropagation();
    }​​
    var inner = document.getElementById('inner');
inner.onclick = function(event)
    {
        alert('inner');
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DYykA/1/

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. I was having trouble applying the `stopPropagation()`, so this helps!

Answer (score 5):

You need to [stop the propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) at the child, so the event doesn't bubble up to the parent.

```
$("#inner").on("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: thanks! I've tried putting this in the javascript, and can't get it to work. I've put `alert`s before and after and i still get the 'outer' alert

Comment: @iight You're adding the handlers directly to the HTML - don't do that. Instead, add it as I did above, with a CSS selector via jQuery.

Comment: thats what i did. I added it as a script, not on the element itsself

Answer (score 3):

use `event.stopPropogation();` to prevent bubbling of event